# Running docker command within python script

Tags: python, docker, python-on-whales

I have a docker image which is using a text search model that I want to call each time I click a button on my streamlit app.

My code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from python_on_whales import docker

def main():
    search = st.text_input('Enter search words:')
    if st.button('Search'):
        st.write('Results:')    
        #Run docker
        docker.run("search_app_image")
        # Read csv and create pandas df
        df = pd.read_csv("results.csv")
        st.table(df)
```

I am trying to run the image the same way as I do in the console via

```
docker run -v "C:\Users\s.woo\Documents\search_app\docker\search-engine:/home" search_app_image
```

to mount it as a volume.

When I run it this way from my python script it doesn't write the data to disk, which I need. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be passing in any additional options to the container.  How are you trying to set that bind-mount option?

Comment: Do you mean via volumes = [] ? I tried putting the path there and it didn't work.

Comment: Fixed this using subprocess and Popen.

Comment: how about a `os.system(docker run ...)` within your script ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount the directory as a volume.
In this case, the call to `docker.run()` should look like the following:

```py
docker.run("search_app_image", volumes=[("C:\Users\s.woo\Documents\search_app\docker\search-engine", "/home")])
```